# Show that set is uncountable

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm having trouble getting started on this proof.

I'm trying to prove that the following set is uncountable:

$B=\{x \in \mathbb{R} : x^2-2x<0\}$

I would appreciate any hints.

Comment: Do you know that intervals are uncountable?

Comment: I should've made that connection, but for some reason didn't think of it... That makes it much simpler :)
I'm guessing the interval has to be a subset of R?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $x\mapsto x^2-2x$ is continuous the set $B$ is open ($B$ is the preimage of the open set $(-\infty,0)$). Every open non-empty subset of $\mathbb R$ is in bijection to $\mathbb R$, hence uncountable. So we have only to show that $B\ne\emptyset$. But that's the case since $1\in B$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: We have $x^2-2x=x(x-2)<0$ precisely when $x>0$ and $x-2<0$, so $B=\ldots$